# app crash when using Explicit intent on itemListner

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent

I have a `ListView`and adapted to `ArrayAdatper` and I want to open new Activity when any Item is clicked, so I used `setOnItemClickListener`and then used `Intent`

```
    ...
    ListView mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,containerAll.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and inseide that `containerAll.class`: I have two Fragments classes:

```
      public class containerAll extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

    ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    fragmentAdapter adapt = new fragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager.setAdapter(adapt);

   }
}
```

when I run each class alone it works but when I but that `Intent` , when I run the app, it crash when I press an Item on the listView.

so does anyone has any idea why this is happening?
this is the the custom adapter class :

```
   public class cAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<arrayObject> {

    public cAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<arrayObject> object){
        super(context,0,object);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Create object from layout
         if(convertView == null){
             convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inside,parent,false);
         }
         arrayObject item= getItem(position);

        TextView distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        // Change image inside the ifnlator
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic);
        image.setImageResource(item.imageRes);

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(item.mName);

        distance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(item.distance != null) {

            distance.setText(item.distance);
            distance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

  }
```

This is the logCat:

```
   09-16 05:22:42.150 8406-8406/com.example.android.mallsguide                 
   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
   09-16 05:22:42.150 8406-8406/com.example.android.mallsguide        
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.android.mallsguide, PID: 8406
                                                                          android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.android.mallsguide/com.example.android.mallsguide.containerAll}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1499)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3942)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:54)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3889)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:708)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
                                                                              at com.example.android.mallsguide.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                              at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:334)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1531)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3667)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5590)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Share your log cats

Comment: @MalikAhsan done

Comment: `ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {...containerAll}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` - Have you?

Comment: @MikeM. I have added it already and it worked, Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all itself. Add you activity in the manifest and the error will be gone.
Like this

```
<activity android:name="YourActivityName" >
</activity>
```

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Worked, Thank you very much

Comment: Good to know :)